# Contract bridge game

Tags: linux, open-source, game

I'm (or rather my grandma is) looking for a contract bridge game, that's:

- Gratis, free and open-source
- Available for Linux (32-bit Debian)
- Preferably using GTK2
- Offline and single-player (and thus has an AI for the other 3 players)

Before she was using [EasyBridge](http://www.stevenhan.com/Old/EasyBridge.htm) on Windows. It's no option to use Wine.

Comment: EasyBridge runs well in Wine. The setup file can be downloaded here: http://www.stevenhan.com/Old/EasyBridge.htm

Comment: That's not something you hear about every day - a grandma switching from Windows to Linux. Was that her idea, or did you "suggest" it? ;)